# How make diable field editable in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on one thing which is collapse-able, SO there is a button called edit when I click on edit I am opening the hidden elements and making the fields editable, but the problem in when I try to write inside that I am getting some error

**My code**

On handle change

```
 const handel_change = e => {
const name = e.target.name;
const value = e.target.value;
setFormData(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
```

};

and on edit

```
 const edit = index => {
setOpen(open === index ? null : index);
setdisabled(false);
```

};

you can check my full working code [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-star-i7egs?file=/src/App.js)

I am getting error as `formData.map is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am using `react-form-hook` there is an option like `defaultvalue` where I can pass my default value and make that field initially disabled, and on edit click I can simply make it enable.

**Working Code**

Just need to replace

`value={item.Last_name}`

with this

`defaultValue={item.Last_name}`

[Code sandbox working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-star-i7egs?file=/src/App.js:2283-2314)